# How to convert Blob (in Sqlite) to Proper String?

Tags: android, arrays, string, sqlite, webview

I had stored HTML file in **SQLite** as Blob data, I try to get data from **`Blob`** we use **`byte[]`** then convert into a **`String`** and load in **`WebView`**, but the issue is some of the special characters like dish `Tall – Taller – Tallest` but return as Tall � Taller � Tallest, How to resolve this issue.

I tried the following method

**1: set data to list_Item**

```
item.setHtml(cursor.getBlob(2));
```

**2: get data from list_Item**

```
String text = new String(item.getHtmlByteArray(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

**3: then load to WebView**

```
webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");
webView.loadData(text, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

I don't want to change store text in SQLite but I want to change in retrieving text, Any solution, Please??

Retrieving text ScreenShot

[image]

**Thanks**

Comment: HTML is plain text. Why not store it as a string?

Comment: Yes, Html is plain text, but actually Sqlite database table contains a column which is Blob format therefor data return in a byte array.

Comment: Not that column type matters much when it comes to sqlite, but... Don't do that. Make it a text affinity column instead.

Answer (score -1):

Replace string with empty character like

```
yourString.ReplaceAll("any special character ","");
```